# Error with NEW to create a function for a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying create a function for a trigger like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION backup_largeobjects_grant()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    GRANT SELECT ON LARGE OBJECT NEW.loid TO backup;
END; $$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this gives me error when it reaches the NEW.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NEW"

I've been looking but not understand that I'm doing wrong.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `GRANT ... ON LARGE OBJECT` statements can't be parameterised; the object ID will need to appear as a literal integer value.

You can achieve this in a stored procedure by building the statement as a string:

```
EXECUTE 'GRANT SELECT ON LARGE OBJECT ' || NEW.loid::text || ' TO backup';
```